# Incorrectly ordered imports using tox

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, pep8, tox

I am trying to make a contribution to django-rest-framework, the imports in authentication file after I run `isort` are like this(I have added import six):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import base64

import six
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model
from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from rest_framework import HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING, exceptions
```

when I run `./runtests --lintonly` it passes all the tests but when I run `tox` it gives me this error:

```
py27-lint runtests: commands[0] | ./runtests.py --lintonly
Running flake8 code linting
flake8 passed
Running isort code checking
ERROR: /home/nitesh/open_source/django-rest-framework/rest_framework/authentication.py Imports are incorrectly sorted.
isort failed: Some modules have incorrectly ordered imports. Fix by running `isort --recursive .`
ERROR: InvocationError: '/home/nitesh/open_source/django-rest-framework/runtests.py --lintonly'
```

Comment: Can you share what code did you add to the django rest framework. It might help me reproducing the issue and finding a solution.

Comment: @Vinit It was hardly 2 lines, `import six` and  replacing `type('')` with `six.string_types` in authentication.py .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see in the REST framework source code (e.g. [here](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3693e938a4e50a7e996c4d1b8dac9d344ac22e48/rest_framework/exceptions.py)), `six` is imported from the `django.utils`. Replacing `import six` with `from django.utils import six` should resolve the `isort` warning:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import base64

from django.utils import six
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, get_user_model
from django.middleware.csrf import CsrfViewMiddleware
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from rest_framework import HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING, exceptions
```

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar error (`Imports are incorrectly sorted`).

`isort` was happy when run directly and failing when running via `tox`. The lines that `isort` was complaining about were:

```
import pytest

from my_module import MyThing
```

`isort`, when run directly, knew that my module `my_module` was a first party (my own) code whereas via `tox` it didn't. So when run directly it was happy with the empty line between `pytest` import and my import, but via `tox` it didn't want to see the empty line because both `pytest` and `my_module` were interpreted as third-party imports.

The solution was to add this line to my `setup.cfg`:

```
[isort]
...
known_first_party = my_module
```